# How to detect if a custom shape has been clicked in godot?

Tags: godot, gdscript

Is it possible to check if a custom shape has been clicked. For instance, how would I check if a piano key, which is not a regular shape, has been clicked. I would assume that you would make an area 2D and make a Collision Polygon 2D, which has your shape, as a child, Then you would send a signal to a script if their was input, and the script would check if it was a click and respond accordingly. I tried this but it is not working. Below is my code. Any help is much appreciated!

```
func _on_Collision_input_event(viewport, event, shape_idx):
    if event is InputEventMouseButton:
        if event.is_pressed:
            $"RadioCPressed".show()
            print("Object Clicked")
        else:
            $"RadioCPressed".hide()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo, it should be `event.is_pressed()` not `event.is_pressed`. It must be giving you an error on run time.

---

Assuming it is not giving you an error, it probably means the method is not running at all (You can use a print or breakpoint at the start of the method to confirm). Also, double check you connected the signal. And make sure the Area has `input_pickable` set to `true`.

Something else you need to consider if whether or not there is something else getting the input. *A common case is that people will use a `ColorRect` or `TextureRect` for background, and leave it with `mouse_filter` set to Stop (which is the default). Even if it is in the background, you need to set `mouse_filter` to Ignore, because Controls take priority over other nodes for input.* See [Using InputEvent](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/tutorials/inputs/inputevent.html).

Comment: Absolute legend, turned out I needed to set my TextureRect's mouse_filter to ignore (as well as adding the brackets to ```is_pressed()```). Thanks!